# Angular filter string array by object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I have two arrays.
First is `$scope.termini` which contains string, and other one is `$scope.reserved` which contains objects. Each of objects has variable `vrijemeTermina`. I want to filter `$scope.termini` by `$scope.reserved[x].vrijemeTermina`.

```
reserve.controller('resCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$watch("pickedDate", function(){
      $scope.termini=["13:00","15:00","17:00","19:00","21:00"];
        $http.post('php/dropdown.php',{"datum":$scope.pickedDate}).success(function(data){
          $scope.reserved = data;
          //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          //alert($scope.reserved[0].datumTermina);
          angular.forEach($scope.reserved, function(value, key){
          $scope.termini = $filter('filter')($scope.termini, value.vrijemeTermina, false);
        });
      });
      console.debug("%o", $scope.termini);
      });
  });
```

I tried so many things that didn't work. Most answers I found filter object arrays by it's property. I didnt find a solution for this problem yet.

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/php/db-conn.php");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$query = "SELECT * from termin WHERE datumTermina='".$data->datum."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
  }
}

$con->close();

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Thats my php file. It returns json that looks like `{0:{"id":"1";"vrijemeTermina":"13:00";"datumTermina":"03/09/2016"}}` I guess.

Comment: You need to inject the `$filter` service into your controller, if your only using filter then perhaps use the [`filterFilter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-controllers-services-and-directives) service

Comment: @papakia hey mate, thanks for answering, that solved one of errors console was giving me, but didnt solve the problem

Comment: What are the other errors that appear in your console ?

Comment: Can you post your JSON?

Comment: I added my php file to question @papakia

Comment: Try to use `$scope.reserved = JSON.parse(data);` because I think `data` is a `String` not an `Object`.

Comment: As Titus mentioned, this could well be your issue. On a side note, if you use `angular.fromJson(data)` instead of `JSON.parse` it will call `JSON.parse` if your value is a string, otherwise it will just return the string. E.g. `$scope.reserved = angular.fromJson(data);`

Comment: i look for date in my database and it returns objects with vrijemeTermina, datumTermina and ID, so i firmly belive they are objects not strings, correct me if im wrong :/

Comment: The `data` variable can be a `JSON` formatted `String` not an `Object` if the server doesn't set the correct headers.

Comment: `[{"ID":"5","datumTermina":"04/09/2016","vrijemeTermina":"15:00"},{"ID":"6","datumTermina":"04/09/2016","vrijemeTermina":"13:00"}]` this is what i get when i stringify `data`. i want to filter 15:00 and 13:00 from `termini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.termini = $scope.reserved.filter(function(v){
   return $scope.termini.filter(function(e){
              return e == v.vrijemeTermina
            }).length > 0;
});
```

This will create an array with all the objects from `$scope.reserved` that have their `vrijemeTermina` value equal to one of the values from the original `$scope.termini` array.

Oh, I've read you're question again and I think your want this to work the other way around.

```
$scope.termini = $scope.termini.filter(function(v){
   return $scope.reserved.filter(function(e){ 
              return e.vrijemeTermina == v
            }).length > 0;
});
```

Comment: hey man, thats was close, i wanted to exclude those results, so i just make it length = 0 and that should work?

Comment: I made it less than 1 and it worked, thanks a lot man, I've been struggling to make it for too long!

Comment: @nytez I'm glad I could help. Good luck. Also, you can use  `..}).length == 0;` instead of `< 1` but both these conditions do the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

How about a pure Javascript solution, using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

```
$scope.termini.filter(function(element, index, array) {

    return element == $scope.reserved[index].vrijemeTermina;

});
```

Is this what you're looking for? It will return an array with all the elements from `$scope.termini` where the corresponding value in `$scope.reserved[i].vrijemeTermina`, by index, matches. If this isn't what you're trying to accomplish, could you be a little clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `vrijemeTermina` property of each object in a for loop like so:

```
reserve.controller('resCtrl', function($scope, $http, filterFilter) {

    $scope.$watch("pickedDate", function() {

        $scope.termini = ["13:00","15:00","17:00","19:00","21:00"];

        $http.post('php/dropdown.php',{"datum":$scope.pickedDate})
        .then(function(response) {

            // make sure your data is parsed
            $scope.reserved = angular.fromJson(response.data);

            // check your data is an array
            if (!angular.isArray($scope.reserved)) {
                console.error("Expected $scope.reserved to be of type Array but is of type " + typeof($scope.reserved));
                return;
            }

            // loop through the array of objects
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.reserved.length; i++) {

                // each iteration filter $scope.termini by the current objects vrijemeTermina value
                $scope.termini = filterFilter($scope.termini, $scope.reserved[i].vrijemeTermina, false);

            }

            console.debug("%o", $scope.termini);

        }, function(error) {

            // good practice to handle errors

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Expected $scope.reserved to be of type Array but is of type object :/

Comment: Ok so you are not returning a list of objects? Try assigning `response.data` to `$scope.reserved`, see my edited code